# I need more info re: The 'fb:app_id' property should be explicitly provided

Tags: facebook

I am just trying to post a link in Facebook to my blog post with the image link to the blog. There are 3 images to choose but none are the one I want. I ran the debugger on the link and got the error.

I then did research that stated I had to use meta data og codes so I inserted them in my site.

I then put this code in my website but it didn't work to give me the picture I wanted:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Brutally Honest"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="Article"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://ghettobastard.com/brutally-honest/i-have-what-you-can-t-buy"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Ghetto Bastard Brutally Honest Blog. An honest view of life, love, the ghetto, money and anything else that comes to mind."/>
<meta property=og:image" content="https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwakeup-world.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2014%2F10%2FLiving-in-the-True-Essence-of-Love.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwakeup-world.com%2F2014%2F10%2F04%2Fliving-in-the-true-essence-of-love%2F&docid=MhcGyxPHmfS_7M&tbnid=bErZKLEsfj57cM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjchcT-mYXjAhUknuAKHezoDpAQMwhIKAEwAQ..i&w=819&h=586&bih=937&biw=1920&q=essence%20of%20%20love&ved=0ahUKEwjchcT-mYXjAhUknuAKHezoDpAQMwhIKAEwAQ&iact=mrc&uact=8/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="416990419028199" />
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=416990419028199&display=popup&href=...
```

These are the error I got.

```
Inferred Property   The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property   The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property   The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property   The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Share App ID Missing    The 'fb:app_id' property should be explicitly provided, Specify the app ID so that stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in url when open the share dialog.
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: ghettobastard.com/brutally-honest/i-have-what-you-can-t-buy does not contain those tags. Looks like you are trying to use Javascript to add them. Facebook does not execute Javascript so that will not work

Comment: Thank you for responding. What should I use then so that the correct picture will post? I was not aware that it was javascript according to the directions to add the og information as well as the ap_id for Facebook. The main blog page has the tags. Website Builder on iPage is what I use. Should I put the og info 
directly on the page for the post?

Comment: My errors have been reduced to: Inferred Property
The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Missing Properties
The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id

Comment: I changed all to <meta content= ’.....’ property= ‘og:title’ /> etc.

Comment: @RussellVann what does your last statement mean? you changed it to single quotes? you flipped content and property attribute order? how did we fix this issue?